# Why is font awesome spinner icon blinking when deployed in jboss but spinning in local?

Tags: angularjs, jboss, font-awesome-5

I have an AngularJS (1.5.3) project using Font Awesome 5 (5.0.6).

Here is the code used to show loading:

```
<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
```

When deployed locally, the spinner functions as expected. But when deployed (minified and bundled as a war file) to jboss on RedHat, the icon blinks instead.

Any idea on how to get the spinner to spin when deployed?

Comment: what is cdn for font awesome?

Comment: @Abhijeet - I'm not using a cdn. I installed Font Awesome using npm